Persistent Volume - Kubernetes Docker Desktop - Doesn't work
I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed with Docker Desktop 4.35.1 with Kubernetes engine enabled.
Docker container with volume mount works perfect but switching to deploy the same container in Kubernetes with persistent volume fails - the mount point in the pod is empty. any advise will be appreciated.
Below are the deployment file and status
Thanks,
Itamar
The deployment file:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: imnginx-deploy
  labels:
    app: imnginx-deploy
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: imnginx-deploy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: imnginx-deploy
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        volumeMounts:
        - name: tmp-volume-name
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      volumes:
      - name: tmp-volume-name
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nginxpv
---
#Create PV and PVC for local storage
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nginxpv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: hostpath
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
   path: "/mnt/nginx/html"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginxpv
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: hostpath
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
# Create external Service for external IP (localhost - 127.0.0.1)
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: imnginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: imnginx-deploy
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30000

Status of Persistent Volume:
$ k describe pv nginxpv
Name:            nginxpv
Labels:          type=local
Annotations:     pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    hostpath
Status:          Bound
Claim:           default/nginxpv
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        1Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:
Source:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /mnt/nginx/html
    HostPathType:
Events:            <none>

PV Claims:
$ k describe pvc nginxpv
Name:          nginxpv
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  hostpath
Status:        Bound
Volume:        nginxpv
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      1Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       imnginx-deploy-56fcdf46dd-nqztw
Events:        <none>

Empty mount in POD:
$ k get pod
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
imnginx-deploy-56fcdf46dd-nqztw   1/1     Running   0          2m21s
$ k exec -it imnginx-deploy-56fcdf46dd-nqztw -- bash
root@imnginx-deploy-56fcdf46dd-nqztw:/# ls -la /usr/share/nginx/html
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   40 Nov 14 12:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 12 02:03 ..
root@imnginx-deploy-56fcdf46dd-nqztw:/# exit
exit

File do exists in host folder:
$ ls -la /mnt/nginx/html/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 admin domain users 4096 Nov 14 14:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 admin domain users 4096 Nov 14 14:15 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin domain users  647 Nov 14 14:16 index.html

